# Paper.js lasso-select tool

Tags: javascript, vector-graphics, paperjs

Has anyone built a free-hand or lasso-select tool for paperjs like you have in Adobe Illustartor?

I was trying to use `intersects(item)` for that, but this only seems to work if my selection path hits any other paths directly and not if there are items inside the selection, even if I colse it before on `onMouseUp`.

`isInside(rect)` looked promising but it can only check if something is inside a rectangle and not free-hand path.

Here is some example:

```
var item1 = Path.Circle(new Point(180, 100), 20);
item1.fillColor = "black";

var item2 = Path.Rectangle(new Point(150, 180), new Size(50, 50));
item2.fillColor = "black";

var selection = new Path([
    new Point(50, 50),
    new Point(50, 250),
    new Point(250, 250),
    new Point(250, 150),
    new Point(150, 150)
]);
selection.closed = true;

selection.strokeColor = "blue";
selection.fillColor = new Color(0, 0, 50, 0.5);

function selectionContains(item) {
    // does not work as expected
    return selection.intersects(item);
}

// should be false
console.log(selectionContains(item1));

// should be true but is false
console.log(selectionContains(item2));
```

Comment: You're looking for the subtractive Boolean Operation. There's a considerable amount of work that was done recently regarding BoolOps, which is included in Paper.js - But just to clear things up, what are you trying to lasso out? Rasters or Vectors? They work differently

Comment: BoolOps did it, see answer below. I'm not hundred percent satisfied since they create and draw extra geometry in Paper.js. I maybe have to add a bounding rectangle pre-check before for performance reasons. Vectors only. Can't imagine how something like this would work for raster graphics.

Comment: If the Raster Image is rectangular (as is usually the case) you can chop off (subtract) using BoolOps, a part of a vector Rectangle that is equal to the width/height of your Raster Image - Then set your Raster Image as a mask/background-image of the subtracted shape.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean operations worked for me. They are not geometric tests and create extra items that have to be removed but it looks like the best solution I can get.
`isEmpty()` tests if the result shape contains any segments after the subtraction.

```
var red = Path.Circle(new Point(180, 100), 20);
red.fillColor = "red";
red.name = "red";

var green = Path.Rectangle(new Point(150, 180), new Size(50, 50));
green.fillColor = "green";
green.name = "green";

var yellow = Path.Circle(new Point(90, 100), 20);
yellow.fillColor = "yellow";
yellow.name = "yellow";

var purple = Path.Rectangle(new Point(160, 190), new Size(30, 30));
purple.fillColor = "purple";
purple.name = "purple";

var selection = new Path([
    new Point(50, 50),
    new Point(50, 250),
    new Point(250, 250),
    new Point(250, 150),
    new Point(150, 150)
]);
selection.closed = true;
selection.strokeColor = "blue";
selection.fillColor = new Color(0, 0, 50, 0.2);


function isInside(_selection, _item) {

    var result = _item.subtract(_selection);
    var insideSelection = result.isEmpty();
    result.remove();

    return insideSelection;
}

function test(_item) {
    console.log(_item.name, isInside(selection, _item) ? " inside" : " outside");
}

test(red); // red  outside
test(green); // green  inside
test(yellow); // yellow  outside
test(purple); // purple  inside
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jsclipper](https://github.com/Delapouite/JsClipper) to intersect polygons.

[This is the original Clipper library](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) and [its documentation](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/_Body.htm).

The [PointInPolygon()](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Functions/PointInPolygon.htm) function might help you.

Comment: Can't find a "path is inside path" geometric test there directly. Looks like this lib ships with 150kb of functionality that paper.js mostly includes. Picking it up in my webpack workflow wouldn't be easy as well since it has no package.json. Do you have an idea of a function or algorithm that I can pick up from there?

Comment: I'm looking for a "PolygonInPolygon" function

Comment: I know, you can check polygon intersections with [paper.Path.GetIntersection()]( http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getintersections-path) ; and then check if there are any path point inside the selection polygon with Clipper.PointInPolygon(). You should check bounding box intersections before using Clipper.PointInPolygon().